# How to get the following output in Python with line breaks added in the input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures

I have the following input (with line breaks) in python.

**Input Code in Python:**

```
input_data = 'AB SSP\n,BCD 110/XYZ/A14/ABD1.112\nAB AAD983/*ABC/0003\nAXYZ AB *SSD* 1:23:05\nAADX'
print(input_data)
```

**Output Code in Python:** (output of the input_data above)

```
AB SSP

,BCD 110/XYZ/A14/ABD1.112

AB ABD983/*ABC/0003

AXYZ AB *SSD* 1:23:05

AADX
```

I want to check in **first line** whether **AB** is present. (independent 'AB' and not mixed in between with any other characters like 'ABD983'). If AB is found, print AB found **and also print the 3rd and 4th line as it is from the output** else skip checking the lines.
Please let me know the code for this in Python.
Thanks in advance !!

Comment: First of all, the last part of your question is not clear. Is the input only consists of 4 lines, and you only need to check the 1st line, or do you mean that this should be repeated for every 4 lines until the end of all lines? And also I have to say even though I posted an answer, but this is not a homework site! You should read about how to ask questions on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Let me explain. Its like this. If "AB" is found in the first line of the input_data (I am telling line number since I have line breaks added), I need to Print the 3rd and 4th line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you need is something like this. I tried to write it clear and simple:

```
import re

input_data = 'AB SSP\n,BCD 110/XYZ/A14/ABD1.112\nAB AAD983/*ABC/0003\nAXYZ AB *SSD* 1:23:05\nAADX'

lines = input_data.split('\n')
for line in lines:
    if re.match('.*(^|\s+)AB(\s+|$).*', line):
        print('AB found')
    else:
        print('-')
```

**Explanation:**

First we break down the text into lines, and then we iterate through those lines and check each one using a module called regular expression or `re` which is used to check for all kinds of patterns in the strings.

Here, I specified that I want an `AB` that is either at the start of the line or is preceded by a white space character, and is either at the end of the line or is followed by a white space character.

And this is the output:

```
AB found
-
AB found
AB found
-
```

#### ANSWER OF YOUR UPDATED QUESTION:

Your explanation is not very clear, but from what I understand you want to only check the first line of the input and if it contains an `AB` then you want to print the 3rd and 4th line. Again, Your explanation is very ambiguous and I'm almost certain that I'm missing something, but anyway here's the code:

```
import re

input_data = 'AB SSP\n,BCD 110/XYZ/A14/ABD1.112\nAB AAD983/*ABC/0003\nAXYZ AB *SSD* 1:23:05\nAADX'

lines = input_data.split('\n')
if re.match('.*(^|\s+)AB(\s+|$).*', lines[0]):
    print(lines[2])
    print(lines[3])
```

Comment: Now if AB is present in first line, I will have to print whatever is there in the third line and 4th line. Else skip reading lines. Could u please help me with that

Comment: I've updated the answer. But I have to say one more time: This is not a homework website! You should work on your problems and if you got stuck, you should come here and tell us about the problem and the things that you've tested. Not just dropping your homework assignment here and ask other people to do it for you! Plus, what you want is pretty simple and should have been able to figure it out yourself using these answers including mine. But anyway I added the answer to your follow up question. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find AB between spaces or other non-letter characters, you can use this code:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'(^|[\W_])AB([\W_]|$)')

print('\n'.join('AB found' if pattern.search(line) else '-' for line in input_data.split('\n')))
```

`\W` literal means all non-letter symbols and doesn't include `_` symbol. Hence, it'd be useful to add this symbol into `[]` characters set.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try the below code

```
input_data = input("Input text")
data=input_data.split(" ")
for i in data:
    if i == "AB":
        print("Whatever you want to print")
    else:
        print("Not there")
```

This should be helpful.

Comment: Fails to identify AB in this scenario. --> 110/XYZ/A14/ABD1.112\nAB (\n is line break but this code sees it as continuation) So if there is AB immediate to \n it fails to identify